# deleting rows from database using jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-roo

I have a table named as ACCOUNT which consists of account_id,position_id and few more columns. Another table I have PositionCombination which consists of colums position_id and few more.

This is the account class which i have

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJpaEntity
public class Account {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
List<PositionCombination> allPositions = new ArrayList<PositionCombination>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

 /*@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<PremiumPlayPositionCombination> premiumPlayPosition = new ArrayList<PremiumPlayPositionCombination>();*/

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<PositionCombinationArc> allPositionsArc = new ArrayList<PositionCombinationArc>();



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Userr user;

public List<PositionCombination> getOrders() {
return null;
}



public List<PositionCombination> getPositions() {
return null;
}

}
```

This is the PositionCombinatin Class

```
package com.uforic.optionstrader.domain;

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooJpaActiveRecord(finders = { "findPositionCombinationsByOrderStatus", "findPositionCombinationsByAccount", "findPositionCombinationsByStrategyType" })
public class PositionCombination {

private int positionType;

/*
 * Strategy type = 1 - Short Term Exit
 * 2 - Calendar Exit
 * 3 - Intraday Exit
 * Currently undefined for normal exit
 */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "strategy_id")
private Strategy strategy;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "positionCombination", targetEntity = AbstractPosition.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<AbstractPosition> positions = new ArrayList<AbstractPosition>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
private Account account;

@NotNull
int orderStatus;


/* 1 - Short term Exit
 * 2 - Calendar Exit 
 */
int strategyType;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="positionCombination", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<StrategyExitReport> exitReports = new ArrayList<StrategyExitReport>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="positionCombination", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<StrategyExitTracker> exitTrackers = new ArrayList<StrategyExitTracker>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="positionCombination", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<IntradayExitDecision> intradayExitDecisions = new ArrayList<IntradayExitDecision>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="positionCombination", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<ExitDecision> exitDecisions = new ArrayList<ExitDecision>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="positionCombination", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

public BigDecimal getTotalCostWithMarginPerContract() {
    BigDecimal totalCostWithMargin = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (AbstractPosition position : positions) {
        totalCostWithMargin = totalCostWithMargin.add(position.getTotalCostPerContract().add(position.getMarginAmount()));
    }
    return totalCostWithMargin;
}

public BigDecimal getTotalCostWithMargin() {
    BigDecimal totalCostWithMargin = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (AbstractPosition position : positions) {
        totalCostWithMargin = totalCostWithMargin.add(position.getTotalCostWithMargin());
    }
    return totalCostWithMargin;
}

public static Integer deletePositions(long accid) {
    return new PositionCombination().deletePositionCombinationByAccount(accid);
}

@Transactional
private Integer deletePositionCombinationByAccount(Long accountid) {
    System.out.println("acc id :" + accountid);
    EntityManager em = PositionCombination.entityManager();
    int result = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM PositionCombination o where o.account.id = :accountid").setParameter("accountid", accountid).executeUpdate();
    return result;
}

public static TypedQuery<PositionCombination> findPositionCombinationsByStrategyTypes(List strategyTypes) {
    EntityManager em = PositionCombination.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<PositionCombination> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM PositionCombination AS o WHERE o.strategyType IN (:strategyTypes)", PositionCombination.class);
    q.setParameter("strategyTypes", strategyTypes);
    return q;
}
```

}

Now when i run this code. It deletes all the entereis from positionCombination Table of that particular account.

```
public void createSquareOff(User user,Account acc)
{
 List<PositionCombination> positionCombinationList = acc.getAllPositions();
 positionCombinationList.clear();
 acc.persist();
}
```

But when I change the code to this . It's not deleting the rows from PositionCombination table. Here I have just done small changes, instead of geting AllPositions i am getting particular Positions from DB on basis of position_id and storing into that positionCombinationList.

```
 public void createSquareOff(User user,Account acc,PositionCombination posComb )
 {
  List<PositionCombination> positionCombinationList = PositionCombination.findPoscomByPoscombination(posComb);
  positionCombinationList.clear();
  acc.persist();
 }
```

Comment: In the second example you are calling persist on an in-memory object that has not been changed in anyway. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: @AlanHay Before clearing I am saving all that data into account table .. But those codes i have not posted.

Comment: Voting to close then.

Comment: @AlanHay My question was why its ubable to delete data when I retrive the data using manual query.

Comment: Because you have  not modifed the object being saved: `acc`. Try this `acc.removeAll( positionCombinationList); acc.persist();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a big difference between the two method implementations.

In the first one, you are getting the *allPositions* attribute from an *Account*. Then you clear all the related *PositionCombination* entities from that relationship.

Take into account the *allPositions* attribute is annotated with *@OneToMany* with the following parameter:

```
orphanRemoval=true
```

It tells the JPA provider to remove the related entities when they are removed from the relationship. That's why all the related *PositionCombination* get removed when you clear the *allPositions* attribute.

In the second implementation you are performing a JPA Query and getting the result as a *List*. That *List* is not an entity attribute, so clearing it won't affect the database or the entities state. You have to remove those entities explicitly. Also you don't need the *Account* instance anymore.